# Magento 2.4.3 upgrade composer dependencies issues

Tags: magento2, upgrade, composer, magento-upgrade

I want to install league/flysystem-cached-adapter 1.1 but it throws the following error on composer require

```
Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires magento/product-enterprise-edition 2.4.3-p1 -> satisfiable by magento/product-enterprise-edition[2.4.3-p1].
    - Conclusion: don't install league/flysystem 2.0.2 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install league/flysystem 2.0.3 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install league/flysystem 1.1.5 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install league/flysystem 2.0.4 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install league/flysystem 2.0.5 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install league/flysystem 2.0.6 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install league/flysystem 2.0.7 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install league/flysystem 1.1.6 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install league/flysystem 2.0.8 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install league/flysystem 2.1.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install league/flysystem 2.1.1 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install league/flysystem 2.2.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install league/flysystem 1.1.7 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install league/flysystem 2.2.1 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install league/flysystem 2.2.2 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install league/flysystem 2.2.3 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install league/flysystem 2.3.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install league/flysystem 1.1.8 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install league/flysystem 2.3.1 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install league/flysystem 2.3.2 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install league/flysystem 2.4.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install league/flysystem 2.4.1 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install league/flysystem 1.1.9 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install league/flysystem 2.4.2 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install league/flysystem 2.4.3 (conflict analysis result)
    - magento/product-community-edition 2.4.3-p1 requires magento/module-aws-s3 100.4.1-p1 -> satisfiable by magento/module-aws-s3[100.4.1-p1].
    - magento/product-enterprise-edition 2.4.3-p1 requires magento/product-community-edition 2.4.3-p1 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.4.3-p1].
    - Root composer.json requires league/flysystem-cached-adapter ^1.1 -> satisfiable by league/flysystem-cached-adapter[1.1.0].
    - league/flysystem-cached-adapter 1.1.0 requires league/flysystem ~1.0 -> satisfiable by league/flysystem[1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2, 1.0.3, 1.0.4, 1.0.5, 1.0.6, 1.0.7, 1.0.8, 1.0.9, 1.0.10, 1.0.11, 1.0.12, 1.0.13, 1.0.14, 1.0.15, 1.0.16, 1.0.17, 1.0.18, 1.0.19, 1.0.20, 1.0.21, 1.0.22, 1.0.23, 1.0.24, 1.0.25, 1.0.26, 1.0.27, 1.0.28, 1.0.29, 1.0.30, 1.0.31, 1.0.32, 1.0.33, 1.0.34, 1.0.35, 1.0.36, 1.0.37, 1.0.38, 1.0.39, 1.0.40, 1.0.41, 1.0.42, 1.0.43, 1.0.44, 1.0.45, 1.0.46, 1.0.47, 1.0.48, 1.0.49, 1.0.50, 1.0.51, 1.0.52, 1.0.53, 1.0.54, 1.0.55, 1.0.56, 1.0.57, 1.0.58, 1.0.59, 1.0.60, 1.0.61, 1.0.62, 1.0.63, 1.0.64, 1.0.65, 1.0.66, 1.0.67, 1.0.68, 1.0.69, 1.0.70, 1.1.0, 1.1.1, 1.1.2, 1.1.3, 1.1.4, 1.1.5, 1.1.6, 1.1.7, 1.1.8, 1.1.9].
    - You can only install one version of a package, so only one of these can be installed: league/flysystem[1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2, 1.0.3, 1.0.4, 1.0.5, 1.0.6, 1.0.7, 1.0.8, 1.0.9, 1.0.10, 1.0.11, 1.0.12, 1.0.13, 1.0.14, 1.0.15, 1.0.16, 1.0.17, 1.0.18, 1.0.19, 1.0.20, 1.0.21, 1.0.22, 1.0.23, 1.0.24, 1.0.25, 1.0.26, 1.0.27, 1.0.28, 1.0.29, 1.0.30, 1.0.31, 1.0.32, 1.0.33, 1.0.34, 1.0.35, 1.0.36, 1.0.37, 1.0.38, 1.0.39, 1.0.40, 1.0.41, 1.0.42, 1.0.43, 1.0.44, 1.0.45, 1.0.46, 1.0.47, 1.0.48, 1.0.49, 1.0.50, 1.0.51, 1.0.52, 1.0.53, 1.0.54, 1.0.55, 1.0.56, 1.0.57, 1.0.58, 1.0.59, 1.0.60, 1.0.61, 1.0.62, 1.0.63, 1.0.64, 1.0.65, 1.0.66, 1.0.67, 1.0.68, 1.0.69, 1.0.70, 1.1.0, 1.1.1, 1.1.2, 1.1.3, 1.1.4, 1.1.5, 1.1.6, 1.1.7, 1.1.8, 1.1.9, 2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.2, 2.0.3, 2.0.4, 2.0.5, 2.0.6, 2.0.7, 2.0.8, 2.1.0, 2.1.1, 2.2.0, 2.2.1, 2.2.2, 2.2.3, 2.3.0, 2.3.1, 2.3.2, 2.4.0, 2.4.1, 2.4.2, 2.4.3].
    - magento/module-aws-s3 100.4.1-p1 requires league/flysystem ^2.0 -> satisfiable by league/flysystem[2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.2, 2.0.3, 2.0.4, 2.0.5, 2.0.6, 2.0.7, 2.0.8, 2.1.0, 2.1.1, 2.2.0, 2.2.1, 2.2.2, 2.2.3, 2.3.0, 2.3.1, 2.3.2, 2.4.0, 2.4.1, 2.4.2, 2.4.3].
    - Conclusion: don't install league/flysystem 2.0.1 (conflict analysis result)
```

The main conflict is as follows:

magento/module-aws-s3 100.4.1-p1 requires league/flysystem ^2.0

but

league/flysystem-cached-adapter 1.1.0 requires league/flysystem ~1.0

How to resolve this dependency?

As far as I checked on packagist the latest version of league/flysystem-cached-adapter is 1.1

https://packagist.org/packages/league/flysystem-cached-adapter

Answer (score 0):

Use this command to ignore the platform requests

```
composer require vendor/module-name --ignore-platform-req
```

A new feature in Composer v2 allows you to selectively ignore platform requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Run below command from terminal

```
composer require league/flysystem 2.x-dev --no-update
```

and then try to run

```
composer update
```